# Facing issue jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/jquery-ui-datepicker1.css" />
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-ui-datepicker1.js"></script>
```

Above labries clashing and search autobox not loading.
when page is load first time and try to input a name then its working fine but when i try to work with another functionality on same page and again try to input in a search box data not loading.

I realise liabraries issue wben i try to move them up and down.

Comment: Please share your full html file.

Comment: Why 2 jquery base libraries? Either use `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` or `jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @Md.DelowarHossen I don't think full html will result in anything good here. First problem is clearly the 2 jquery references. Second Op should check console to see what the error is.

Comment: You should remove the jquery 1.4.2 (as that's effectively what your code does, but removing it would be clearer).   As is, given *only* what you've provided, the two jquery's will not be a problem as the 2nd removes the 1st before the 1st actually does anything.   The issue might be based on exactly which version of jquery-ui you've included as it will need a specific version of jquery.  Please include which version of jquery-ui you have.

Comment: Ideally, please create a snippet [edit] and click `[<>]` that *demonstrates* the issue - you'll need to use matching CDNs rather than "../assets" and you'll need just enough (and only enough, not "full") HTML to be able to demonstrate/reproduce the issue here - see [mcve]  The [jquery-ui SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui/info) page will give you a started, but you need the same versions as you're using.

Comment: Please create [mre] to save time of users and read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.